# Can't set headers in Node js and sqlite3

Tags: json, node.js, express, sqlite

Hi I am struggling with this error for quite some time and even tho I found many similar issues I am not able to solve it. If you could have a look to my code and give me an advise I would appreciate it a lot!

```
//Register User
router.post('/register', function(req,res) {
var email = req.body.email;
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
var password2 = req.body.password2;


//Validation 
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);



var errors = req.validationErrors();


if (errors){
    res.render('register', {
        errors:errors
    });

} else {
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users ( id, username, email, password, salt) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    stmt.run([ username, email, hashPassword(password,'salt'), 'salt'],function(error){
                    if(error) {
                    res.render('register', {
                    error:'Email is already taken'
                        });
                    };
                }).finalize();
        req.flash('success_msg','You are registered and can now login');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
}
 });
```

I assumed the issue is the last `res.redirect('/users/login');` and I also try return statements, but even tho it still throws me this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/Users/SGI02144/IdeaProjects/login/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/Users/SGI02144/IdeaProjects/login/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
at done (/Users/SGI02144/IdeaProjects/login/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:956:10)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/SGI02144/IdeaProjects/login/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/utils.js:26:13)
at runCallback (timers.js:574:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)
```

Comment: Because you are returning data two times to the response ( user already, and redirect) manage to get one one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `res.render('register'...` is trying to send back a response on the error https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render after the `res.redirect('/user/login')` https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect.

I would suggest putting 

`req.flash('success_msg','You are registered and can now login');
res.redirect('/users/login');`

in the callback of `finalize` or `finalize.then()`